# How can I add my custom UI from PSD to Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently been going over some HTML and CSS stuff to get more into web development, I have been designing sites on and off for a while now and I would love to start actually developing some.

I've seen Bootstrap mentioned so many times all over the internet and I was wondering if someone could help me out and point me in the right direction... I've been learning the fundamentals of HTML/CSS and as I understand it, Bootstrap is a html/css UI framework?

I have my own UI designs in a PSD file, how would I get them to work within Bootstrap?
Is it a matter of slicing up my images and adding custom CSS into Bootstrap?

I know that I am a long way off from this, but this is the type of stuff I want to be doing: 
http://heyflat.com/themes/todo/index.html

If you can point me towards the type of stuff I should be learning in order to get there I would much appreciate it, so far I will continue with my html/css stuff but I would love to start using Bootstrap and customizing it seems essential to me for what I would like to be able to achieve...

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Overall, my process has not changed much except for how I think about converting PSDs to HTML and CSS. I look forward to the day I discover a tool as flexible and comfortable as Photoshop that can output directly to good HTML and CSS. That day has yet to come to me. Here's the process I follow, utilizing Photoshop and Bootstrap.

1. I find that Photoshop is a great way to imagine, share and iterate over a visual design because it frees me to experiment in ways that are currently either impossible or too time consuming to realize just with HTML and CSS.
2. Once a design is agreed upon, I begin planning how the target design will be realized with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

   - I consider the browsers of my target audience. For example, IE8-, does not support rounded borders. If IE8- users are a large portion of my audience and those rounded borders are critical to the design I may take the time to slice out images and add extra HTML and CSS.
   - I decide if I am going to use a framework like bootstrap. Browser support must also be considered when deciding on a framework. If a framework has examples like bootstrap then I can checkout those examples in various browsers. If using a framework then I commit to doing it their way. That is, I use their grid system, html and class names for everything. I only add my own when the framework cannot meet a specific need. I do augment their classes as needed using a separate stylesheet but always in appropriate, low risk ways, bootstrap encourages this.  I will probably never augment the grid system except perhaps through their customizer, but I have never needed to do that.
3. Next I implement the design. I may find that some elements need to be sliced out of the PSD, but most, like drop shadows, rounded borders and gradients, can be rendered using CSS. Some aspects of the PSD may need to be tweaked to accommodate responsive behavior or to make implementation simpler. As has always been the case, I target standards compliant browsers first and adjust for the others later. One of the nice parts about a good framework is that there is usually very little that needs tweaked.
4. I review the document at various resolutions in browsers my target audience use, and consider and implement additional tradeoffs as needed.  For example, if it is not critical that those rounded corners show up in IE8- then I will keep it simple, render them using CSS, and let IE8- alone. I still verify that it looks acceptable in IE8 and IE7.

Steps 4 and 5 are generally not sequential but steps I bounce back and forth on. Also, make sure your client is on board or you can get them on board with how you are supporting various (not-so-modern) browsers and your reasons for doing so (shorter load times, less development time, easier maintenance, and so on).

- Bootstrap 2 examples: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#examples
- Bootstrap 3 examples: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: Hmm, well I know how to splice up my PSD with that tool. I was asking if that is the right process to add the custom look to the Bootstrap?

I will like you said have to make some changes with the design, thank you for this set of info I will play around with Bootstrap as is a little more first and then try to make some changes to having it look custom, again thanks!!

Comment: I understood your question as how would you go about doing this. I wouldn't claim that there is one "right" process but a lot of good ones and circumstances can determine what is best at a specific time. For example, once a design has been implemented in HTML and CSS it may be faster/easier/more useful to try out different ideas directly in HTML and CSS then going back to the PSD. It all depends, but if I'm just getting started I tend to use Photoshop and go from there.

Comment: Also, by using Photoshop or something like it, you decrease the chances of your design looking like a tweaked bootstrap example :)

Comment: Thank you for adding more to your answer and taking the time to reply again, it's making more sense now! 

So far I do all of my design work in Photoshop I just want to jump into development and using something like Bootstrap seems like it would help me a great deal, a lot of people have said so too and that example I linked to is the kind of stuff I want to eventually end up being able to create utilizing the Bootstrap framework.

You're awesome, thank you for your time :P

(Hmm I need 15rep before I can say the answer was helpful *facepalm*)